# Custom Action when specific node-type content is created in drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a requirement where the admin will upload an excel file to the site. Once the file is uploaded the data has to be imported to a table. And data from the table will be synchronized to nodes if they are present else new node is created. My question is i can do the synchronization using hook_cron but i have to import the data of excel file to a specific table on creation of node. How can i fire a custom action on a specific  node type of node creation in drupal 6?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hook_nodeapi`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) with the `$op` of `insert`.

You will get a reference of the node, where you can test the node type and do what you need to do.

Comment: Can we use it as below ?

function hook_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'insert':

      my code in this place;

      break;
  }
}

Comment: @Satya You need to replace the hook part of the function name with the module you write the hook in. But otherwise it looks fine. This is how hooks in drupal work.